# Create a Bitmap image to show an hour worked using c#

Tags: c#, image, .net-core, time, bitmap

I am trying to make a Bitmap image to represent a block of one hour and show red as worked time and white as non-worked showing in periods of 10 minutes intervals. I am trying to get the result to look like below:

[image: One hour block showing red for worked in 10 minute intervals]

Any help or guidance would be greater appreciated. In the code below Tuple<int,DateTime>> the int is time block example 0,1,2,3.....21,22,23,24 and DateTime will hold the time worked.

```
public void DrawPeriod(IGrouping<int, Tuple<int, DateTime>> worked)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(640, 480);

    for (var x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
        {
            bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
        }
    }

    bitmap.Save("worked.bmp");
}
```

Comment: This looks as if you are not really in command of your data. As it stands you are coloring all pixels without looking at your data at all. You should at least scale the hour range (24h) to the bitmap and test for the minutes worked. The way to go would be to calculate a rectangle with X (or Left) being the hour and Width the minutes. Y (or Top) and height a arbitrary constants. Then you use `graphics.FillRectangle(r Brushes.Red)`  in a loop. `graphics` would be created as `using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {...your loop..}`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't give a sample with the data you needed. But you can do it something like this. This can be achieved by using `System.Drawing.Graphics`.

```
var sampleData = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 13, 4, 5, 6, 12, 7, 8, 9 };
var bitmapHeight = 250;
var barWidth = 50;
var bitmap = new Bitmap(sampleData.Length * barWidth, bitmapHeight);
int currentX = 1;

foreach (var item in sampleData)
{
    var result = item % 2;
    Brush brush;

    if (result == 0)
    {
        brush = Brushes.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        brush = Brushes.White;
    }

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle(currentX, 0, barWidth, bitmapHeight);

        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rectangle);

        // Set Text
        Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        graphics.DrawString(item.ToString(), drawFont, drawBrush, currentX + 15, bitmapHeight / 2);
    }

    currentX = currentX + 50;
}

// Border
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5), new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
}

bitmap.Save(FileName);
```

**Sample Output**

[image]